# cordova firebase analytics plugin not working

Tags: cordova-plugins, html-framework-7

I am using firebase analytics cordova plugin(here is the link.  https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics) but having some issues with using it.

Here are some code snippets that I used.

```
cordova.plugins.firebase.analytics.logEvent("Share Post", {page: "Email", link: gArticle.link}).then((res) => alert(JSON.stringify(res)))
.catch((error) => alert(JSON.stringify(error)));
```

I have google-services.json and GoogleService-Info.json files on the root folder of my cordova app.

When I run the app, I always get "OK" as a response(no error) but I can't see any logged events on my firebase console.
Is there any idea for fixing this issue?

Thanks in advance.